# changing several objects with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking for a solution for following:

**For JQuery**: 
How can I change the attribute of all parents of objects that have the same name?

**Here is my code:**

```
<div class="roundedOne">
  <input type="radio" id="id_single" name = "radStatus" value = "1" />
  <label for="id_single"></label>
</div>          

<div class="roundedOne">
  <input type="radio" id="id_married" name = "radStatus" value = "1" />
  <label for="id_single"></label>
</div>
```

I want to do something like :
$("[name='radStatus']").parent().attr("class", "myNewClassName");

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 $(function(){
    $("[name='radStatus']").parent().attr("class", "myNewClassName");
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ku3vJ/)

Your code is working. but You need, how to implement. see demo

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("input[name ='radStatus']").parent().addClass("myNewClassName");
```

---

Comment: Thanks everyone.
I have found this post very usefule.

(I don't know how closing this issue) - consider this as closed.

Thanks, again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) jQuery method.

So this:

```
$("[name='radStatus']").parent().attr("class", "myNewClassName");
```

Becomes this:

```
$("[name='radStatus']").parents().attr("class", "myNewClassName");
```

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKTuF/) that will change all the parents of the elements. Inspect the elements to see the new class name.